# golang swagger annotations for rest api

Tags: go, swagger

I have written swagger annotations for my REST APIs. However swagger documentation is created only for the last declaration (for a particular endpoint). Is it possible to create swagger documentation through annotations for non unique endpoints?

My code can be found here -  https://github.com/SejalAbhangrao/go_web_app_with_swagger_and_test_cases/blob/master/book_handlers.go

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: endpoints must be unique. However you can define different response structure based on HTTP Response Code

Comment: Usually we have same end points for different methods (GET, POST). Is there any way that we could write swagger annotations for these methods so that swagger creates documentation accordingly?

Comment: Ah, yes, you can have different methods with different interface for one endpoint. What's your code ?

Comment: Hey Alex. Thank you for taking your time out to help me. You can find my entire code at https://github.com/SejalAbhangrao/go_web_app_with_swagger_and_test_cases .  getBookHandler and createBookHandler are my GET and POST methods respectively for the /book endpoint. However the swagger documentation that gets generated happens only for POST method.